# R - find outliers in time series dataset using standard deviation

Tags: r, time-series

i have a xts time series object with  numeric values for the data. str (dataTS)

`An ‘xts’ object on 2014-02-14 14:27:00/2014-02-28 14:22:00 containing:
  Data: num [1:4032, 1] 51.8 44.5 41.2 48.6 46.7 ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXlt,POSIXt] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:

 NULL`

I want to find the data points that are more than (2 * s.d.) away from mean.
I would like to create an new dataset from it.

`[,1]
2015-02-14 14:27:00 51.846
2015-02-14 14:32:00 44.508
2016-02-14 14:37:00 41.244
2015-02-14 14:42:00 48.568
2015-02-14 14:47:00 46.714
2015-02-14 14:52:00 44.986
2015-02-14 14:57:00 49.108
2015-02-14 15:02:00 1000.470
2015-02-14 15:07:00 53.404
2015-02-14 15:12:00 45.400
2015-02-14 15:17:00 3.216
2015-02-14 15:22:00 49.7204`

the time series.
i want to subset the outliers 3.216 and 1000.470

Comment: Just `scale` your full data to have zero mean and unit standard deviation (i.e. Z-transform your data); then it's easy to identify which points are `> 2 sd` away from the mean.

Comment: You don't provide a minimal sample dataset, so I've added an example based on some  sample data below. Please take a look.

Comment: sample provided in the question

Comment: i solved by using ` meanD = mean(data); sdD = sd(data) outliers=  subset(data, (data[,1] > meanD + 2 * sdD) | (data[,1] <  meanD - 2 * sdD) )  `

Comment: You've manually scaled values; that works too of course. You can simplify the last command by summarising the two conditions as `abs(data[, 1] - meanD) > 2 * sdD`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `scale` your data to have zero mean and unit standard deviation. You can then directly identify individual observations that are `>= 2 sd` away from the mean.

As an example, I randomly sample some data from a Cauchy distribution.

```
set.seed(2010);
smpl <- rcauchy(10, location = 4, scale = 3);
```

To illustrate, I store the sample data and scaled sample data in a `data.frame`; I also mark observations that are `>= 2` standard deviations away from the mean.

```
library(tidyverse);
df <- data.frame(Data = smpl) %>%
    mutate(
        Data.scaled = as.numeric(scale(Data)),
        deviation_greater_than_2sd = ifelse(Data.scaled >= 2, TRUE, FALSE));
df;
#         Data Data.scaled deviation_greater_than_2sd
#1    8.007951  -0.2639689                      FALSE
#2  -34.072054  -0.5491882                      FALSE
#3  465.099800   2.8342104                       TRUE
#4    7.191778  -0.2695010                      FALSE
#5    2.383882  -0.3020890                      FALSE
#6    3.544079  -0.2942252                      FALSE
#7   -7.002769  -0.3657119                      FALSE
#8    4.384503  -0.2885287                      FALSE
#9   15.722492  -0.2116796                      FALSE
#10   4.268082  -0.2893179                      FALSE
```

We can also visualise the distribution of `Data.scaled`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Data.scaled)) + geom_histogram();
```

[image]

The "outlier" is 2.8 units of standard deviation away from the mean.

Comment: Note that `ifelse(Data.scaled >= 2, TRUE, FALSE)` can be reduced to just `Data.scaled >= 2` .

Comment: thank you for your answer...it does find the outlier..but my dataset is a timeseries type xts. i updated the question with the sample data

Comment: @StefaniaAxo Please use `dput` to provide (part of your) sample data.